# ReactiveMongoDB saveAll() with 100K documents at a time efficient alternatives?

Tags: spring-webflux

I configured a few `@Scheduled()` jobs on my **WebFlux** project and
in each job I fetch some data from external APIs and save some documents using **ReactiveMongoDB**.

Each job is trying to save about 100000 documents at a time using `ReactiveMongoRepository.saveAll()`.

The problem in this case it is taking way too long to complete this task: about 2 hours.

Each document is as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb16de94761926f75940599"),
    "subdivision1ISOCode" : "DH",
    "subdivision1Name" : "Dhamār",
    "subdivision2ISOCode" : "",
    "subdivision2Name" : "",
    "cityName" : "Dhamar",
    "timeZone" : "Asia/Aden",
    "geoNameID" : 76184,
    "localeCode" : "en",
    "continentCode" : "AS",
    "continentName" : "Asia",
    "countryISOCode" : "YE",
    "countryName" : "Yemen",
    "europeanUnion" : false,
    "_class" : "project.domain.maxmind.location.GeoLite2CityLocation"
}
```

Is there a better/faster alternative to save all this documents at once?

**UPDATE**

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = Milliseconds.DAY)
private void synchronizeGeoLite2CityLocations() {
    this.updateFlux().subscribe();
}

private Flux<Tuple3<GeoLite2CityLocation, GeoLite2CityNetworkBlockIPv4, GeoLite2CityNetworkBlockIPv6>> updateFlux() {
        Flux<GeoLite2CityLocation> cityLocationFlux = this.geoLite2CityLocationService
                .saveAll(this.maxMindAPIService.getCityLocations())
                .onErrorContinue(DuplicateKeyException.class, (e, o) -> {
                });

        Flux<GeoLite2CityNetworkBlockIPv4> cityBlockIPv4Flux = this.geoLite2CityNetworkBlockIPv4Service
                .saveAll(this.maxMindAPIService.getCityBlocksIPv4())
                .onErrorContinue(DuplicateKeyException.class, (e, o) -> {
                });

        Flux<GeoLite2CityNetworkBlockIPv6> cityBlockIPv6Flux = this.geoLite2CityNetworkBlockIPv6Service
                .saveAll(this.maxMindAPIService.getCityBlocksIPv6())
                .onErrorContinue(DuplicateKeyException.class, (e, o) -> {
                });

        return Flux.zip(cityLocationFlux, cityBlockIPv4Flux, cityBlockIPv6Flux);
}
```

where the `saveAll` method is calling the ReactiveCrudRepository<T, ID>

```
<S extends T> Flux<S> saveAll(Publisher<S> var1);
```

Comment: can you please post your implementation.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, just updated the question with code

Comment: and what does the api you are fetching from look like `maxMindAPIService.getCityLocations()` what type of API, rest? blocking?